Deactivate tls encryption in Kubernetes control plane
I would like observe packets exchanged between elements of the control plane but they are tls encrypted.
I've been using wireshark and minikube. Since decrypting the packets seems rather complicated I tried to modify configuration files and manifests located in the virtual machine at /etc/kubernetes to deactivate tls but without any success (most of the time the control plane pod just crashes).
I'm particularly interested in the kube-controller-manager and wonders if it is possible.
